# Current Culture changes once it enters the background worker

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, backgroundworker

I am facing one issue in WPf application intially when my application load the **CurrentCulture** of application like **FI**,but in between it enters background worker resets to **en-US.**

According to study if it enter background thread it resets the locale to OS set locale,for that i even tried this by changing system locale but it didn't worked for me.

Please suggest anything.

Comment: Did you try this in your `BackgroundWorker`? : `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = yourCulture`

Comment: @Pikoh if i use this within worker it gives you reset culture..my problem is that background worker resets culture..reason fro me unkown.....

Comment: [See also](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2386727/4137916).